# How to set value from Choice-Chips to Text-Field in Flutterflow

Tags: widget, textfield, flutterflow

I have a flutterflow project similar to G-Pay. My aim is to create a payment page which accepts MPIN, transaction amount and product name. Few products are listed in Choice-Chip, the user can either choose a  product from Choice-Chip or can enter it manually. The current issue is that user can either type the product or choose it from Choice-Chip, both actions are not working simultaneously. One more issue is that when user chooses the product from Choice-Chip it is shown in the text-field, but not passed to the API, ie value is not taken for processing. The textfield and MPIN field are given inside a Form, while choosing value from Choice-Chip it shows 'This field is mandatory!', ie field is empty..

I have tried the same with the help of creating a new variable in Flutterflow and assigning condition to that variable. Still it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.